# Chrome is showing this site cannot be reached

Tags: networking, hot-spot

When I try to access any website in either Chrome or Firefox through my phone's hot-spot, I see "This site cannot be reached.  Site is either down or relocated".

But in terminal, nslookup and ping do connect to that server.

It is same in Ubuntu and Windows.

I have tried clearing dns-cache and also network reset. Issue continues.   Anyone has any idea about it?

Comment: does it work well with `lynx` (web navigator inside terminal - that's not really beautiful, but it helps) ?

Comment: You can also check at https://downfor.io to see whether the website is down for you only!

Comment: Some sites will not connect if you are using an blocker, not many but a few.  Is it a lot of sites(or all)  or just the odd one?  Can also try changing DNS provider.

Comment: It is for all sites. even for google.com. i tried to update chrome by wget, it showed ssl error

Comment: As a side note, ping and nslookup does not determine if a server is hosting a service responding on port 80. Use `telnet {addr} {port}` -> `telnet google.com 80`

Comment: Try to use another DNS provider.  A couple are 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, or 9.9.9.9.  You say it is happening in windows and ubuntu, so I think you need to add these to your router.

Comment: @crip659 I'm no network expert, but if he can do a nslookup with correct response, does that not mean DNS provider is not the issue?

Comment: @Smurfz87  you are probably correct.  I am less an expert than you.

Comment: Are you using another network/router/ISP to connect to askubuntu?

Comment: i am using my phone's hotspot

Comment: can your phone reach sites if connected to the network, or do you have other machines that can connect?

Comment: In phone, everything is working fine

Comment: Do you have your network manager under IPv4 settings set to automatic DHCP, or addresses only?  Don't know windows settings.

Comment: Your phone company can block hot-spot connections through the phone but allow you to connect from the phone's browsers and other apps. 1) Were you able to use a web browser on a PC through the phone hot-spot before? 2) Does your phone's plan include hot-spot service?  3) Which cellular phone company do you use? Please click [edit] and answer 1-3 by putting the answers in your question. Please don't answer with Add Comment; your answers and any questions to us should go in the Question.